# Migrating AWS EC2 m3.large to m4.large

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization

New m4 instances look much better than previous m3 instances (regarding performance and pice), so I'm going to make them as default instances for our cloud services. These services ran before on m3 instances, so I wanted to perform a regular upgrade using 'change instance type' option. But it seems like it's not available for m3-to-m4 migration. I know, that it is possible to 'move' service from one instance to another by creating a disk image from an original one and then starting a new instance based on that image. The question is, whether it is possible to perform this migration in more elegant way? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Spin up a new m4 and configure it with your configuration management system. Take a bit of downtime to migrate data and you're all set. If you don't have a configuration management system, now is as good a time as any to get started. By doing so, you'll never find yourself in this situation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

### 1 - Reprovision

As EEAA mentioned, you can bring a new instance up, either configure it using a configuration management tool (if the server is used in production, you should be using configuration) or restore a backup, and then migrate your services and re-point DNS.

This approach is very simple if you use configuration management or autoscaling.

### 2 - Resize

#### 2.1 EBS-backed instances

You can manually resize your instance via the Amazon console. See the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#resize-ebs-backed-instance) for detailed instructions.

This approach is useful when you have a standalone instance.

#### 2.2 - Instance Store-Backed instances

If you use an **instance-store-backed** instance, you will need to migrate by creating an AMI of your instance, destroying your current instance and creating a new instance using the AMI you just created. Details on how to do this are in the same [Amazon documentation resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#resize-instance-store-backed-instance).

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

1. Start an Ubuntu HVM linux, any version, new
2. Start an Ubuntu / with my existing AMI / PVM linux, and install grub packages on them: `apt-get install  grub-pc  grub-pc-bin grub-legacy-ec2 grub-gfxpayload-lists`
3. Stop PVM linux
4. Detach root (/dev/sda1) partition at PVM linux
5. Attach PVM linux root partition to running HVM linux somewhere, e.g.: /dev/sdf
6. On HVM linux: `mkdir -p /mnt/xvdf && mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/xvdf`
7. `rsync -avzXA /boot/ /mnt/xvdf/boot/`
8. `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/xvdf/dev && mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/xvdf/dev/pts && mount -o bind /proc /mnt/xvdf/proc && mount -o bind /sys /mnt/xvdf/sys`
9. `chroot /mnt/xvdf`
10. `grub-install --no-floppy --recheck --force /dev/xvdf`
11. `update-grub2`
12. exit chroot: CTRL+D
13. stop HVM Linux
14. detach /dev/sda1 original root AND detach /dev/sdf PVM root
15. attach PVM root to HVM linux as /dev/sda1
16. Start HVM linux, voilà!
17. Create a new AMI image from the running HVM linux, it will be HVM virtualized.

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26276763/edit

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a few minutes of downtime:

- Create the m4 instance, but do not start it, and do not create or attach storage
- Stop the m3 instance
- Attach the existing EBS volume from the m3 instance to the new m4 instance
- Start the m4 instance. It should behave the same as the m3 instance